# Parse SDK - Javascript httpRequest format params

Tags: javascript, rest, parse-platform, syntax, postman

The body section of my `httpResponse` object has the following map

```
body: {
    "keys": 1,2
},
```

Where my API requires a list of integers to be passed in the `"keys"` key

The problem is that javascript syntax considers the comma after the `1` to be a syntax error. Which is correct, it will cause a syntax error in javascript.

This API responds correctly to passing just one integer, but I need to pass several, at once.

I tried `encodeURIComponent(1,2)` and while this does solve my javascript syntax error, the server is only interpreting the first value `1`. Which does not create the objects server side correctly. Whatever encodeURIComponent does isn't working, so I tried to encode the comma itself `1%2C2` where `%2C` is comma. This also causes a Javascript syntax error.

In `PostMan`, a network request tester, I verified that the api only responds successfully to a list of integers in this format: `1,2` , not `1%2C2`, not `1, 2`, not `"1,2"` not `"1, 2"` or any string, array denoted by brackets, etc.

So somehow I have to pass up `1,2` but this currently causes a javascript syntax error, changing the API is not an option as I do not maintain it or have access to the server (and other applications use this API), any advice?

Comment: I must be misunderstanding... isn't it simply `body: { "keys": [1,2] }`

Comment: @danh no, the api returns 400 bad request with that syntax

Comment: can you post the code that makes the request, including the code that forms the parameter?

Comment: @Dahn It really isn't helpful, I've detailed the syntax that works, and the syntax that doesn't work. It is a problem with associative arrays in java (and my API of course)

Comment: Okay, not sure I understand the last comment.  The parse functions require syntactically correct JSON as params, and the unbracketed 1,2 isn't.  Sorry I can't be of further help.

Comment: @danh thanks, I can optionally try to add a different library that does http requests, but we will see

Comment: What is the content type that your API is expecting or accepts (json, XML, text, html, etc)?  Once you definitively give us this information we can better help you.  It sounds like it's json and if it is you will have to have valid json to post the data as you noted in your question.  The question I believe is how your api maps the json to create the server map.

Comment: @GartuanTezMaximus x-www-form-urlencoded